# how to iterate over a dictionary when one of the properties is a list

Tags: c#

I built a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, Student> students = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
```

over the following class:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

StudentId is the key.  Now I want to iterate over the dictionary and print each StudentId and student Name, as well as a list of the courses that each student is enrolled in.  I know how to iterate over the dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Student> student in students)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = String.Format("<br />Student ID: {0}  Student Name: {1} ", student.Key, ???);
```

but I don't know how 1) to print out the student and 2) to iterate over and print the list of courses for each student.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for `student.Value` in place of `???`. Just go `student.Value.Name` etc. For the courses, it's the same: use `foreach (Course course in student.Value.Courses)`.

Comment: `foreach(Student student in students.Values) ...`

Comment: If you literally are not able to understand how to retrieve the _value_ component of the `KeyValuePair<int, Student>` instances that are enumerated by your `foreach` loop, then you have a much deeper lack of comprehension of C# than can be reasonably addressed in a single Stack Overflow answer. I recommend that you invest some more time learning how C# objects are declared, and reading the documentation for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, so that you understand how each works, and their relationship to each other.

Comment: Thanks Asad.  I don't know how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments to your question it may be beneficial to gain a better understanding of KeyValue pairs and iterators. Nonetheless, when you have a nested structure as you show above and want to print it out on a single line, the `String.Join` function comes in handy.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Student> student in students)
{
     var courses = String.Join(", ", student.Value.Courses);
     var output = String.Format("ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Courses: {2}", student.Key, student.Value.Name, courses);

    // Alternatively you could iterate over the courses here
    // foreach (Course course in student.Value.Courses) ...

     resultLabel.Text = String.Concat("<br />", output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Student> students = new List<Student>() {
                   new Student(new List<int>() {100,103,106}) { StudentId = 1001, Name = "John"}, 
                   new Student(new List<int>() {101,104,105}) { StudentId = 1002, Name = "Mary"},
                   new Student(new List<int>() {102,105,104}) { StudentId = 1003, Name = "Tom"},
                   new Student(new List<int>() {103,106,102}) { StudentId = 1004, Name = "Dick"},
                   new Student(new List<int>() {104,101,102}) { StudentId = 1005, Name = "Harry"}
                };

            Dictionary<int, Student> dictStudents = students.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Student> student in dictStudents)
            {
                string message = String.Format("<br />Student ID: {0}  Student Name: {1} Courses: {2}", 
                    student.Key.ToString(),
                    student.Value.Name,
                    string.Join(",", student.Value.Courses.Select(x => "CourseID=" + x.CourseID.ToString() + ":" + "Course Name= " + x.Name).ToArray()));
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        public Student() { Courses = new List<Course>();}
        public Student(List<int> couseNumbers)
        {
            Courses = new List<Course>();
            foreach(int id in couseNumbers)
            {
                Courses.Add(Course.courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == id).FirstOrDefault()); 
            }
        }
    }
    public class Course
    {
        public static List<Course> courses = new List<Course>() {
                new Course() {CourseID = 100, Name = "abc"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 101, Name = "abd"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 102, Name = "abe"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 103, Name = "abf"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 104, Name = "abg"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 105, Name = "abh"},
                new Course() {CourseID = 106, Name = "abi"}
        };

        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```